# Ckeditor upload image error Undefined index: CKEditorFuncNum

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying upload image but getting error, image is successfully uploading to folder /server/uploads/ but in console im getting error:

> Notice: Undefined index: CKEditorFuncNum in
>   C:\xampp\A_websites\site.ru\public\dashboard\vendors\editor\uploader\upload.php
>   on line **55**
>   window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(,
>   'http://site.ru/server/uploads/Screenshot_18.png', 'Screenshot_18.png
>   successfully uploaded: \n- Size: 8.85 KB');

How I can fix it?

Config.js

```
config.extraPlugins = 'uploadwidget,uploadimage,filebrowser';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/dashboard/vendors/editor/uploader/upload.php'
```

;

Upload.php:

```
<?php
$upload_dir = array(
    'img'=> '/server/uploads/',
);

$imgset = array(
    // 'maxsize' => 2000,    
    // 'maxwidth' => 900,    
    // 'maxheight' => 800,    
    'minwidth' => 10,      
    'minheight' => 10,
    'type' => array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'),
);

// If 0, will OVERWRITE the existing file
define('RENAME_F', 1);

$re = '';
if(isset($_FILES['upload']) && strlen($_FILES['upload']['name']) >1) {
    define('F_NAME', preg_replace('/\.(.+?)$/i', '', basename($_FILES['upload']['name'])));  //get filename without extension

    // get protocol and host name to send the absolute image path to CKEditor    
    $site = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
    $sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['upload']['name']));
    $type = end($sepext);    // gets extension
    $upload_dir = in_array($type, $imgset['type']) ? $upload_dir['img'] : $upload_dir['audio'];
    $upload_dir = trim($upload_dir, '/') .'/';

    //checkings for image or audio
    if(in_array($type, $imgset['type'])){
        // list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);  // image width and height
        if(isset($width) && isset($height)) {
            if($width > $imgset['maxwidth'] || $height > $imgset['maxheight']) $re .= '\\n Width x Height = '. $width .' x '. $height .' \\n The maximum Width x Height must be: '. $imgset['maxwidth']. ' x '. $imgset['maxheight'];
            if($width < $imgset['minwidth'] || $height < $imgset['minheight']) $re .= '\\n Width x Height = '. $width .' x '. $height .'\\n The minimum Width x Height must be: '. $imgset['minwidth']. ' x '. $imgset['minheight'];
            if($_FILES['upload']['size'] > $imgset['maxsize']*1000) $re .= '\\n Maximum file size must be: '. $imgset['maxsize']. ' KB.';
        }
    }

    else $re .= 'The file: '. $_FILES['upload']['name']. ' has not the allowed extension type.';

    //set filename; if file exists, and RENAME_F is 1, set "img_name_I"
    // $p = dir-path, $fn=filename to check, $ex=extension $i=index to rename
    function setFName($p, $fn, $ex, $i){
        if(RENAME_F ==1 && file_exists($p .$fn .$ex)) return setFName($p, F_NAME .'_'. ($i +1), $ex, ($i +1));
        else return $fn .$ex;
    }

    $f_name = setFName($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. $upload_dir, F_NAME, ".$type", 0);
    $uploadpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. $upload_dir . $f_name;  // full file path

    // If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors
    if($re == '') {
        // print_r($_FILES);exit;
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) {
            $CKEditorFuncNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'];
            $url = $site. $upload_dir . $f_name;
            $msg = F_NAME .'.'. $type .' successfully uploaded: \\n- Size: '. number_format($_FILES['upload']['size']/1024, 2, '.', '') .' KB';

            $re = in_array($type, $imgset['type']) ? "window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url', '$msg')"  //for img
           : 'var cke_ob = window.parent.CKEDITOR; for(var ckid in cke_ob.instances) { if(cke_ob.instances[ckid].focusManager.hasFocus) break;} cke_ob.instances[ckid].insertHtml(\'<audio src="'. $url .'" controls></audio>\', \'unfiltered_html\'); alert("'. $msg .'"); var dialog = cke_ob.dialog.getCurrent();  dialog.hide();';
        }
        else $re = 'alert("Unable to upload the file")';
    }
    else $re = 'alert("'. $re .'")';
}

@header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo '<script>'. $re .';</script>';
```

Answer (score 4):

Please add `config.filebrowserUploadMethod  = "form";` in config.js which resides inside ckeditor file

Answer (score 0):

`config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/dashboard/vendors/editor/uploader/upload.php'`

Just add CKEditorFuncNum parameter on above config.

`config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/dashboard/vendors/editor/uploader/upload.php?CKEditorFuncNum=1'`